# Printer server hostname changed - deploy printers via GPO no longer works

Tags: group-policy, printing, network-printer

We use the Deploy Printers feature of local group policy in Windows 8.1, so that our users can log into any machine and printers will already be configured. This was working flawlessly for all users on all machines until the hostname of our print server changed. Now the policy appears to be doing nothing. I already took out all the old deployed printers and redeployed using the right server name and printer names. Windows found the new print server just fine, and manually connected to the printers works.

I've tried using Deploy Printers in both the machine policy and the user policy without any luck. gpupdate /force does nothing, nor does rebooting the machine entirely. Any help is appreciated!!